# How to prevent href=# from activating multiple instances of a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navbar with multiple internal links.

```
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
```

And, I have a jQuery function which runs in every 2 seconds.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    setInterval(playSlideShow(), 2000);

    function playSlideShow() {
         // codes to change slide
    }
});
</script>
```

The problem is whenever I click on navbar link (with `href="#"`), it creates a new instance of interval which runs `playSlideShow()` in every 2 seconds. For example, if I clicked on navbar links for 5 times, the slide is changed 5 times in 2 seconds instead of 1 time in 2 seconds.

How to prevent it?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is not the actual code for the Anchor being clicked. Could you provide real code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
$('.navbar a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

This will prevent the links from reloading the page. Note that the anchors need to be wrapped in an element with the class `navbar` for this example to work:

```
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the interval in a variable, then when it's clicked, either delete the interval or ignore it. Here's an example

```
//Initialize timer variable
var timer = false;

// Start timer
timer = setInterval(timerName, 1000);

// End timer
clearInterval(timer);
timer = false;
```

That's all the functionality you need, in your click event just add:

```
if(!timer){
   // Timer is off, create new interval
}
```